# conv1d problems with simple example

Tags: tensorflow

Two simple example about conv1d:  1 dimension features: 
`
[1, 0, 2, 3,0, 1, 1] convolved by [2, 1, 3], the outputs is [  8.  11.   7.   9. 4.], this is right. But for the two dimension features: "[[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1],   [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1]]" this convolved by "[[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]" should output "[[  8.  11.   7.   9.   4.],        [  8.  11.   7.   9.   4.]]"

`

But the program output:

```
[[  2.   1.   3.]
[ 10.   5.  15.]
[  2.   1.   3.]
[  4.   2.   6.]
[  4.   2.   6.]
[  6.   3.   9.]
[  4.   2.   6.]]
```

Where is the problem? Any help will be appreciated.*

```
import tensorflow as tf
i = tf.constant([1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='i')
print(i.shape)
ii = tf.constant([[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1],[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1]])
print(ii.shape)
k = tf.constant([2, 1, 3], dtype=tf.float32, name='k')
k2 = tf.constant([[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]], dtype=tf.float32, name='k')
print(k2.shape)

data = tf.reshape(i, [1, int(i.shape[0]), 1], name='data')
data2 = tf.reshape(ii, [1, int(i.shape[0]), 2], name='data')

kernel = tf.reshape(k, [int(k.shape[0]), 1, 1], name='kernel')
kernel2 = tf.reshape(k2, [1, int(k2.shape[0]), 3], name='kernel')
print(kernel2)

res = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv1d(data, kernel, 1, 'VALID'))
res2 = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv1d(data2, kernel2, 1, 'VALID'))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(kernel2))
    print sess.run(res)
    print sess.run(res2)
```

Comment: Feature: [[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1]] Filters: [[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]

Comment: Try printing the value inside `data2`. I think it will be different from what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

1) The tf.nn.conv1d default input format is [batch, in_width, in_channels], in your case it's [2,7,1] (for data2)

2) Convolution kernel is the same across batches, so you don't need to clone kernel for each batch, unless you want to apply **different kernels for the same input**, which will results in more channels in the output. (f.e. [2,7,2])

Thus if you want to get the mentioned result, the code should be as following:

```
k = tf.constant([2, 1, 3], dtype=tf.float32, name='k')

data = tf.reshape(i, [1, int(i.shape[0]), 1], name='data')
data2 = tf.reshape(ii, [2, int(i.shape[0]), 1], name='data2')

kernel = tf.reshape(k, [int(k.shape[0]), 1, 1], name='kernel')

res = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv1d(data, kernel, 1, 'VALID'))
res2 = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv1d(data2, kernel, 1, 'VALID'))
```

Comment: Thanks your clear answer. But I want to implement the following operation: Each row of the feature(two rows in my example) will convolved with different kernel (here we have two kernels). Can you help to explain how to do this? [[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1],[1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1]] XX [[2, 1, 3], [4, 1, 2]] ==>[ [ 8. 11. 7. 9. 4.], [ 11. 20. 21. 19. 23.]]  This may be is to apply different kernel to the different input.  [[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1],[1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1]] is a 2D image, [[2, 1, 3], [4, 1, 2]] is a 2D kernel

Comment: @void well the best way would be to separate them into different operations. Or if you still want to run them at once, is implement slicing afterwards and slice 2 out of 4 outputs, but this becomes tidious. The whole implementation of tf.nn.conv1d is designed to optimize the convolution operation over multiple batches by converting those inputs and kernels into a product of 2 matrices.

Comment: @void  And this is implemented as converting kernels into [number_ofkernels, kernel width] matrix and input into [batches, kernels_size, number_of_receptive_fields]. So there is no way to avoid applying all kernels to all images using tensorflow library. On the other hand, I don't really see why would you need that? As that's not a common practice in Neural Networks, that's not faced with tf.nn library.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to illustrate how the Conv1D works in two ways as bellow.

[image]
Let's see how we can transfer Conv1D also a Conv2D problem. Since Conv1D is usually used in NLP scenarios we can illustrate that in the bellow NLP problem.
[image]

First let's do that using a Conv2D method:

```
cat = [0.7, 0.4, 0.5]
sitting = [0.2, -0.1, 0.1]
there = [-0.5, 0.4, 0.1]
dog = [0.6, 0.3, 0.5]
resting = [0.3, -0.1, 0.2]
here = [-0.5, 0.4, 0.1]
sentence = tf.constant([[cat, sitting, there, dog, resting, here]]
# [batch, in_width, in_channels]: [1, 6, 3]
data = tf.reshape(sentence), (1, 1, 6, 3))
# we reshape [batch, in_width, in_channels] to [batch, 1, in_width, in_channels] according to the quote above
# each dimension in the embedding is a channel(three in_channels)
f1c1 = [0.6, 0.2]
f1c2 = [0.4, -0.1]
f1c3 = [0.5, 0.2]
# filters = tf.constant([[f1c1, f1c2, f1c3]])
# [out_channels, in_channels, filter_width]: [1, 3, 2]
# here we have also only one filter and also three channels in it. 
filter1D = tf.transpose(tf.constant([[f3c1, f3c2, f3c3]]), (2, 1, 0))
# shape: [2, 3, 1] for the conv1d example
filters = tf.reshape(filter1D, (1, 2, 3, 1))  # this should be expand_dim actually
# transpose [out_channels, in_channels, filter_width] to [filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]] and then reshape the result to [1, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
output = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv2d(data, filters, strides=(1, 1, 2, 1), padding="VALID"))
# the numbers for strides are for [batch, 1, in_width, in_channels] of the data input
# <tf.Tensor: id=119, shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.9       , 0.09999999, 0.12      ], dtype=float32)>
```

Let's do that using Conv1D(also in TensorFlow):

```
output = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv1d(sentence, filter1D, stride=2, padding="VALID"))
# <tf.Tensor: id=135, shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.9       , 0.09999999, 0.12      ], dtype=float32)>
# here stride defaults to be for the in_width
```

Hope that helps.